# What is a calling signature?

Tags: signature

I'm reading [Django Docs for the Model Class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model) and it says to:

> ...take care not to change the calling signature as any change may prevent...

I've heard of calling signature before, I've always assumed it was the function name, but then I question why they would mention something so obvious.

I checked Wikipedia and it only gave me results for [type signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) which I think is the same?

If I'm wrong, then what is a calling signature? And more importantly, how do I not alter it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the arguments( and their arrangement), keyword arguments which you are going to use to call a method. The line mentioned from documentation meant that if you are overriding the `__init__` method for a model class, you need to keep the arguments and keyword arguments same as original Model class's implementation.